# Single row container for grid-template-columns and responsive window

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Suppose I have about 250 divs styled with class `slider-item`. I have a responsive grid in css `A` which wraps the divs as columns/items as the window scales. Minimum item width is `240px` listed below.

https://streamable.com/l3ezfv

I'm trying to keep the grid responsive in a single row (nowrap with overflow horizontal). The problem is the property `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill..)` grows/shrinks rows b/c the divs exceed the current window width

**A**

```css
.slider-content {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr)); 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
} 

/* .slider-content > .slider-item {
  min-height: 130px;
  min-width: 240px;
} */
```

**B**

```css
.slider-content {
display:grid;   
grid-auto-flow:column;  
grid-gap:10px; 
margin:20px 0;
overflow:auto;
}

.slider-content > .slider-item {
  min-height: 130px;
  min-width: 240px;
}
```

Css `B` keeps the content in a single row with horizontal scroll, but the problem is its not responsive like css `A`

I need it later for a multiple column carousel.

Not interested in flexbox or slickjs; using css grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this achieves what you want:

```
.slider-content {
    display: grid;
    overflow-x: auto;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(240px, 1fr);
}
```

And don't forget to set a height on either `.slider-content` or `.slider-item`.

**Update**

I don't know how to disable CSS grid row wrapping. But, I found a way that works like on the video, but in one row with overflow. It is not the most elegant way, but works just fine. I didn't add all the media queries for up to 6 columns, but it is very easy to add them - just increment the media size up 240px, or whatever you want the minimal width to be, and change the `grid-auto-columns` value.

```
.slider-content {
    /* Same as above, before update. */
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .slider-content {
        grid-auto-columns: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 719px) {
    .slider-content {
        grid-auto-columns: 50%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .slider-content {
        grid-auto-columns: 33.3%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not responsive like `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill`. When the window is maximized or narrow, the row does not adjust columns.  
See https://streamable.com/l3ezfv, I want that variable column count but in one row (+overflow)

Comment: I see, I updated the anwser. I hope it will help you.